# How do i fix my pygame window, always being a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

this my first time on Stacks overflow, first of all, so plz do not kill me if I format wrong, but I am trying to run this code, but every time I do the Pygame screen just turns black, and every time my cursor goes on top of the screen, it becomes one of the spinning donuts, that mean that windows is having a hard time processing. If anyone could please help me, figure out what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it, thx in advance by the way.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

ss_images = [
    pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('C:/Users\\Wonka101\\PycharmProjects\\Images\\ss1.png'), (64, 64)),
    pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('C:/Users\\Wonka101\\PycharmProjects\\Images\\ss2.png'), (64, 64))
]

screen = (500, 500)

bg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users\\Wonka101\\PycharmProjects\\Images\\space v.2.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, screen)

win = pygame.display.set_mode(screen)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x_position, y_position, width, height):
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.velocity = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.fly_count = 0

    def draw(self):
        while True:
            win.blit(ss_images[self.fly_count], (self.x_position, self.y_position))
            self.fly_count = self.fly_count + 1
            if self.fly_count == 2:
                self.fly_count = 0


def game_window():
    global fly_count
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    ss.draw()
    pygame.display.update()


ss = Player(250, 250, 64, 64)
running = True
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    game_window()
```

Comment: You have `while True` in your draw function with no exit condition (`break`) this is an infinite loop

Comment: so how would i fix this???

Comment: It depends, why are you blitting those images in a loop? Do you mean to render each image on alternate frames?

Comment: yes, exactly thx by the way so far

Comment: Your code would work exactly as you wanted if you just remove the while loop. On each draw `fly_count` is incremented meaning that the next draw will blit the next image

Comment: why did the while loop crash my code, becasue it worked, but i dont understand y

Comment: Because your code was in the while loop it never processed any events, a window that is not processing any events is considered to be "unresponsive". This is why you need to call `pygame.event.get()` on every loop